# Attribute error in python won't go away

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Why do I keep getting

```
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

or my code? How can I fix this?

```
import string

infile = open('alice_in_wonderland.txt', 'r')

text = infile.readlines()

counts = {}

for line in text:
    for word in line:
    counts[word] = counts.get (word, 0) +1
'''
if word != " ":
if word != ".":
'''         

word_keys = counts.keys()
word_keys.sort()

infile.close()

outfile = open("alice_words.txt", 'w')
outfile.write("Word \t \t Count \n")
outfile.write("======================= \n")
for word in word_keys:
outfile.write("%-12s%d\n" % (word.lower(), counts[word]))
outfile.close()
```

I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To produce a sorted list of keys, use:

```
word_keys = sorted(counts)
```

instead. This works in both Python 2 and 3.

In Python 3 `dict.keys()` does not return a list object, but a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). You could call `list()` on that object, but `sorted()` is much more direct and saves you two additional calls.

I see that you appear to count words in a file; if so, you are instead counting *characters*, not words; `for word in line:` iterates over a string, so `word` is assigned individual characters from the line.

You should be using [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter

with open('alice_in_wonderland.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # assumption: words are whitespace separated
        counts.update(w for w in line.split())

with open("alice_words.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("Word \t \t Count \n")
    outfile.write("======================= \n")
    for word, count in counts.most_common():
        outfile.write("%-12s%d\n" % (word.lower(), counts[word]))
```

This code uses the file objects as context managers (with the `with` statement) to have them closed automatically. The `Counter.most_common()` method takes care of the sorting for us, not by key but by word count.

Comment: Wow, Thanks alot, you're the man. I was going at trying to fix line 9-11 for some reason.